# What does `/usr/lib/apt/methods/copy` do?

Tags: apt

What does `/usr/lib/apt/methods/copy` do? I'm sitting in a meeting, idly watching the top processes reported by `conky` (in Debian Jessie), and it has popped up a few times in the last couple hours. I tried a google search but only saw results for other utilities in that directory and couldn't quickly find a `man` page for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [source](https://github.com/chaos/apt/blob/master/apt/methods/copy.cc):

```
// -*- mode: cpp; mode: fold -*-
// Description                                                          /*{{{*/
// $Id: copy.cc,v 1.7.2.1 2004/01/16 18:58:50 mdz Exp $
/* ######################################################################
   Copy URI - This method takes a uri like a file: uri and copies it
   to the destination file.

   ##################################################################### */
                                                                        /*}}}*/
// Include Files                                                        /*{{{*/
```

Further reading:

- [APT Method Interface: Chapter 2 Specification](http://www.fifi.org/doc/libapt-pkg-doc/method.html/ch2.html) 
  The documentation explains the terms, e.g.,

> The two internal methods, **`copy`** and **`gzip`**, are used by the acquire code to parallize and simplify the automatic decompression of package files as well as copying package files around the file system. Both methods can be seen to act the same except that one decompresses on the fly. APT uses them by generating a copy URI that is formed identically to a file URI.